# How to play video player in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to be able to click on a tableview item and play the video.so I wrote some of the code for video player.I am using MPMediaplayer framework.I am using json parser.Using json parser to retrieve the data from webserver. My problem is when a user clicks on a UITableView cell is that the video player opens full screen and it just says "loading..." the entire time and the video does not load, no errors are reported either in the debugger.Please help me any body..Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    urlsArray=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

-(void)loadData
{
    url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"urls”];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
    if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])      
    {
    }
    else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
        NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]init];
        array=[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"video-urls"];        
        dataDictionary=[array objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);    
    }
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key1”]]; 
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key2”]]; 
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key3”]];
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key4”]];
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key6”]];       
    NSLog(@"%@",urlsArray); 
} 

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedIndex=indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"%@ %d",urlsArray,selectedIndex);
    NSString *currentUrlsArr=[urlsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *urlString=[NSURL URLWithString:currentUrlsArr];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlString];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayer play];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Check whether you are getting the currentUrlsArr or not

Comment: @user3419311 make sure you are checking it over iOS device not on the simulator

Comment: is urlString created?

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the frame of the movie player view.  As Apple [show themselves](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem

`moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlString];`

after this you missed this method to call

```
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: bro i still i got same problem bro

Comment: bro i got json response bro

Comment: You may correct till getting currentUrlsArr value as a JSON, But creating of the MPMoviePlayer you need to pass a valid NSUrl, cross check NSUrl created org not..